# Keyerror: ID during adding of this line df4 = pd.read_csv('../input/riadd-dataset/RFMiD_Training_Labels.csv',sep='\t')

Tags: python, data-augmentation

When i am writing this line

```
df4 = pd.read_csv('../input/riadd-dataset/RFMiD_Training_Labels.csv',sep='\t')
```

this shows me the following error shown below.

```
    File "<ipython-input-11-2b86b3a98ba3>", line 14, in <module>
df = dataframe_creation()
File "<ipython-input-11-2b86b3a98ba3>", line 4, in dataframe_creation
df4['ID']="Training/"+df4['ID'].astype(str)+'.png'
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2980, in >> 
 __getitem__
 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
KeyError: 'ID'
```

Comment: Working fine in my pc. Do you really have `ID` column in your dataframe? Check for spelling mistake.

Comment: I have ID column in my data. same spelling. i am running in spyder

Comment: Can you show us the full code?

Comment: It is solved. In the above error we can ignore sep='\t'. by ignoring the sep, problem is ressolved

Answer (score 0):

```
**In the above error ignore **sep='\t' write below line**.
```

`        df4 = pd.read_csv('../input/riadd-dataset/RFMiD_Training_Labels.csv')

`
< Write this code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).